# Qt: element visible and not obscured (no need to scroll)

Tags: c++, qt4

From the Qt doc about the visible property:

> This property holds whether the widget is visible. [...]
>
> A widget that happens to be obscured by other windows on the screen is
> considered to be visible

In my case, there is no other window but only the same window with scroll bars (horizontal and vertical).

how can I know if the element is in the visible area (really visible by the user, without scrolling)?

Comment: what view you are using ? ListView, Grid or custom view with scroll area ?

Comment: customview with scroll area but actuallly, I would need to know that for each possible case as this would be useful in the future as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a [`QScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qscrollarea.html) you can use its member function

```
void ensureWidgetVisible ( QWidget * childWidget, int xmargin = 50, int ymargin = 50 )
```

to make sure your widget is visible. For item views (anything inherited from [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html)), there is

```
virtual void scrollTo ( const QModelIndex & index, ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible ) = 0
```

which makes sure that the element represented by `index` is visible.